Ledermann rails settings implementing Mobility translation
Currently, I was trying to add a mobility on a rails settings model.
I have this model named an artist.rb
class Artist < ApplicationRecord
  extend Mobility
  translates :name, type: :string

  has_settings do |s|
    s.key :dashboard, :defaults => { :theme => nil }
  end
end

Then, i created a file under app/models named setting_object.rb
module RailsSettings
  class SettingObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    extend Mobility
    translates :value, type: :hash
  end
end

Results:
:en
@artist.name: 'mike en'
@artist.settings(:dashboard).theme: 'theme en'

:es
@artist.name: nil
@artist.settings(:dashboard).theme: 'theme en'

Wherein, I'm expecting :es locale

@artist.settings(:dashboard).theme: nil

Base on how the mobility standard usage.
